# Setting up Django-nonrel with Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, django-nonrel

I am trying to develop an web app using:
- MongoDb as the database
- Django as the web framework

I am encountering a few problems which makes me doubt the quality of this approach
my setup is:
- MongoDb installed and properly working 
- Django-nonrel, djangotoolbox and DjangoMongoDBEngine are installed in a virtualenv with Python 3.4
- Os is Windows 7 enterprise
- Using Pycharm as the editor
- my settings in settings.py are

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_mongodb_engine',
        'NAME': 'jungle1',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': 27017
    }
}
```

Unfortunately when I run through the tutorial at http://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html
I get a ImproperlyConfigured exception, which I am having difficulty solving.

Has anyone had experience with a similar setup?

Is there any glaring mistake or omission that anyone could spot?

Is it a sound approach at all? - for instance would it be more productive to try and use MongoEngine instead? Or even use bottle.py with pymongo?

Thanks a lot for the help

Marc

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you clear value of Engine then it should work like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
#        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
#        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        'ENGINE': '',
        'NAME': 'mydb',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': 27017,
    }
}
```